# UITableView has cells, but shows no cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

So, the correct number of rows shows up. On pressing any row, the correct action takes place. However, the cells themselves are nowhere to be seen.

I added a `NSTimer` in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

for each cell just to trace it out beyond the function - they all say that **their superview is equal to the tableview in question (and is not nil, so i'm not checking `nil == nil` or something).**

They all contain labels with the correct text.

The separator lines are  being drawn.... If I change the TableView background, the whole visible area's background shows as that color.

I'm checking that each cell is neither hidden nor set to an alpha of 0.

Is there anything else I could be missing?

Answer (score 1):

Are you loading from your cells from a nib file or creating programmatically?

Are you overlaying another object over your cell in the cell subview? Perhaps a subview is covering it; I can't tell, since you have not posted any code yet. Given the information you have provided, it is difficult to determine why you cannot see the cells backgroundView.

Try changing the color with

```
UIView *tmpView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
tmpView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
myCell.backgroundView = tmpView;
```

It sounds like you have set the backgroundView of your cell to [UIColor clearColor].

Comment: I have no idea what happened, I was actually setting the background color to [UIColor grayColor] and no difference appeared. I manually set the font for the label, and suddenly everything worked correctly. My guess is that for whatever reason, the font specified in the nib was invalid and was crashing loading from the nib? That doesn't fully answer my concerns though...